# How to access local site from other computer on windows PC

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

On my linux pc i access webisite by going  http://site1.local

I have setup virtual host in httpd.conf

I want that when i should be able to access that address from windows PC.

In the windows hosts file i have written

```
192.168.1.81 site1.local
```

But still i can't access the page.

i can ping that adress but not get the webpage to work

Comment: in your `httpd.conf` at your `virtual host` is it binded to 192.168.1.81 or all interfaces ? is your firewall blocking anything on your server by any chance ? you might want to say which OS youre using on both it might help others to answer you. every bit piece for information you can provide will help solving your problem.

Comment: i am using centOS 5 , the virtualhost is binded to 127.0.0.1:80. I have checked iptables and haven't seen any rule blocking any PORT

Answer (score 1):

You can change your virtual host from 127.0.0.1 to your network ip which is `192.168.1.81:80` or you can make it `*:80`.

I would recommend the 2nd option so it will keep working on both, internaly on the server and within your internal ip.

The reason it won't work for your other computer is probably because it is bounded to 127.0.0.1.

So it would be:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
```

The `NameVirtualHost *:80` is needed so it won't let other sites conflict with each other, but make sure you have only one entry of NameVirtualHost in your httpd.conf or vhosts.conf.

Comment: i tried that but i still can't access from other computer

Comment: You should put in your windows hosts file the exactly name you have inside your virtualhost ServerName in your apache server otherwise it won't know where the users  wants to go. so for example if you have `ServerName my.domain.com` then at your windows hosts file you must make it `192.168.1.81 my.domain.com` if that is the ip to your server

Comment: forgot to say also make sure you have restarted apache to make the changes happen, `service httpd restart`

Comment: i have done the same , i can ping that name but it does not open in browser , i have restarted apache aswell

Comment: It might be a firewall issue then, but you already created a question about it so i will just go there and try to help you with what i can ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should be a matter of checking if apache is listening on port 80 with

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep :80
```

for which you should see your apache and IP:PORT that it is listening on.

If it listens on the right interface (or on all interfaces) then it can be a problem of the right firewall or name resolution on the other local station.

HOSTS file might be or not be fine, test if it works over `http://192.168.1.81`